# Writing resource files to USB

Tags: c#, resources, copy, usb

I want to write files from my C# resources into a USB drive when it is plugged in. I already got the code working which detects if a USB drive is inserted. The problem I encounter is writing the resource files, here is what I tried:

```
if (File.Exists(e.Drive + "\autorun.inf") == false ) {
    File.Copy(@"Resources\update.ico", e.Drive);
    File.Copy(@"Resources\autorun.inf", e.Drive);
}
```

`e.Drive` contains the path of the inserted USB stick (e.g F:\). I get an error message:

> Could not find a part of the path 'F:\'.

Comment: Dubious... I'm going to hazard a guess that they're using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program to detect a new device and overwrite its autorun with their own. But that's just a guess.

Comment: yes , i do not have the skill yet to write something like this (the usb detect thing ) on my own. not ashamed to admit that.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using the article. I simply meant that what you are doing with it is dubious.

Comment: why ? my autorun.inf changes the icon and the name of the usb, whats wrong with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) cannot be just a folder, you have to supply the complete path.

Comment: e.Drive contains F:\ so should be ok, no?

Comment: no, read the docs.  "The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file."

Comment: @Preet No, you need a destination filename. `File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName)`

Comment: it worked ! i changed it to File.Copy(@"Resources\update.ico", e.Drive + "update.ico"); thanks man :)

Comment: great!  If it worked, please mark this answer as Accepted (green checkmark)

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the `\` at the front of `\autorun.inf` or use an @ string

```
if (File.Exists(e.Drive + "\\autorun.inf") == false ) {
    File.Copy(@"Resources\update.ico", e.Drive);
    File.Copy(@"Resources\autorun.inf", e.Drive);
}
```

or

```
if (File.Exists(e.Drive + @"\autorun.inf") == false ) {
    File.Copy(@"Resources\update.ico", e.Drive);
    File.Copy(@"Resources\autorun.inf", e.Drive);
}
```